# Blacklisted IPs visiting my site

Tags: php, ip-address, blacklist

I have a website and I wanted to see what volume of traffic I was receiving, using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

However, when checking these IP addresses against blacklisting services I found that around 97% of them are shown as being blacklisted.

Should this be of concern to me or is it quite normal for that type of traffic to connect?

Comment: Most of the IP blacklists I know about are for email.   There are lists of blacklisted open relays and spam farms.   Where did you find a blacklist for web requests?

Comment: Are you using google analytics tool?
you can filter and protect spam list IPs in google analytics.
you can reference realted content [google analytics filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en).

Comment: I checked the IPs against the IPVoid website mainly.

Answer (score 1):

They have likely been blacklisted as being the source of spam, or attempts to penetrate logins or to exploit vulnerabilities.

Should you be concerned?  Depends on your site - are you collecting data or selling something?  Yes.

Do you have a static page advertising pet grooming etc?  No.

Comment: Thanks. I do have some pages that connect to SQL, so I'm guessing that could be an issue in that case.  I've also noticed some slow down on the site, but not sure if this is related to the IPs, but I'll probably put some block on them as advised by seo pine above.